# PHP on IIS 7.5 Slow through browser but fast through command-line

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5, php-5.6

I have a php script that has a for loop that downloads some pdf/jpg files from AWS.

I'm currently testing it and it is downloading 180 files which total about 64MB.

When I call the script through the browser using http://localhost/script.php, the script takes about 10-12 minutes to completely finish.

If I call the same script from the command prompt by running c:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe -f "c:\WebApps\scripts.php" the complete script runs in about 5 seconds and downloads all the files correctly.

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this huge discrepancy?

I am using PHP 5.6 on IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2.

Comment: when you call it from the browser, the request first goes to web server. Depending on your server conf (cgi, fast-cgi for IIS) the time taken to execute your script may vary. So it takes up more resources than from command line. I find it wise to do these kind of task where no user interaction is required using cron jobs through cli

Comment: I understand there may be a difference but there is an over 100x difference in execution time on the same exact script.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue by changing the method I was using for downloading the files.  I was initially using file_put_contents and I switched over to curl.

I am using the following function:

```
function retrieveandsave($url, $pathtosave, $filename){
if (!file_exists($pathtosave)) {
    mkdir($pathtosave, 0777, true);
}

$fp = fopen ($pathtosave . $filename, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );
curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
fclose( $fp );
```

}

Comment: you should have added the code to the question itself.